# Ubuntu Software doesn't work and why are there two Software Center in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-center, 20.04

I completely erased the old disk data and installed the 20.04 LTS version of Ubuntu but the **Ubuntu software** on the dock doesn't start. Then I ran in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-software
```

It went fine. But still it doesn't open. Then I searched in dash for "**software**" and found two software center. One named **Software** and other **Ubuntu Software**. **Software** starts but **Ubuntu Software** doesn't start. In the dock there is **Ubuntu Software** which doesn't start.

[image: Two software center]

Another thing, Running `sudo apt update` says `All packages are up to date` but in the **Software** it shows 2 updates needed. This is strange.

[image: software center]

Why there are two software centers? One of them starts and the other doesn't. The one which starts shows pending updates but in terminal there is no pending updates.

**Update:** According to first answer I ran `snap-store` form terminal and got this:

```
16:30:11:0219 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
16:30:11:0225 Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
16:30:14:0571 Gs  plugin appstream took 3.0 seconds to do setup
16:30:14:0580 Gs  enabled plugins: desktop-categories, fwupd, os-release, packagekit, packagekit-local, packagekit-offline, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-refresh, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit-url-to-app, appstream, desktop-menu-path, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-popular, modalias, odrs, packagekit-refine, rewrite-resource, packagekit-history, provenance, snap, systemd-updates, generic-updates, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
16:30:14:0581 Gs  disabled plugins: dpkg, dummy, fedora-langpacks, fedora-pkgdb-collections, repos
16:30:16:0144 Gs  /etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf file not found
16:30:17:0235 Gtk Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/433/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/snap-store/433/data-dir/icons/Yaru/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the pre-installed Ubuntu Software is a [snap package](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started) (source: [article on OMG! Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/02/ubuntu-snap-store-transition)). You can check this by running the following command:

```
snap list
```

You should see an entry called `snap-store` which corresponds to the pre-installed Ubuntu Software.
You are supposed to be able to run the pre-installed Ubuntu Software by running the `snap-store` command in Terminal. If it fails, it should show some useful error messages.

Secondly, the pending updates shown in the GUI application are updates for two pre-installed snap packages. That's why they don't appear in the list of packages that can be upgradable by `apt`.

Comment: I have added the output of `snap-store` in my question.

Comment: @Smie That's good, but consider reporting a bug at launchpad.net with that output instead. Your original question was why there are two software centres, I believe that is covered already.